# Integrals from a non-analytic point of view

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, integration, big-picture

I've mentioned before that I'm using this forum to expand my knowledge on things I know very little about. I've learnt integrals like everyone else: there is the Riemann integral, then the Lebesgue integral, and then we switch framework to manifolds, and we have that trick of using partitions of unity to define integrals.

This all seems very ad hoc, however. Not natural. I'm aware this is a pretty trivial question for a lot of you (which is why I'm asking it!), but what is the "correct" natural definition we should think of when we think of integrals?

I know there's some relation to a perfect pairing of homology and cohomology, somehow relating to Poincare duality (is that right?). And there's also something about chern classes? My geometry, as you can see, is pretty confused (being many years in my past).

If you can come up with a natural framework that doesn't have to do with the keywords I mentioned, that would also be very welcome.

Comment: Do you know the Lebesgue integral just for R^n or for arbitrary measure spaces?  If the former, then the latter might be what you're looking for.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology

Comment: @Will: That shows that integrals, as we already defined, work to define cohomology. But it doesn't get to the essence of what we want integrals to do (and then maybe we can define integrals to be any definition that does that?). In any case, having done number theoretic algebraic geometry for so long, I wonder what the essence of integrals (a tool I don't see very often in my work) is. What function do they provide? Is being an alternate way of defining cohomology really their only function?

Comment: @Ricky: I forget. My last encounter with such ideas was roughly 13 years ago. But I'm looking for abstraction in a more categorical, rather than analytic, approach.

Comment: I suppose you could say that an integral is a bilinear pairing between $k$-forms on a manifold and $k$-cycles that satisfies some axioms (it is a fun exercise to figure out what those axioms are), but I'm not convinced that that is a very enlightening thing to do.

Comment: There is no single "natural" theory of integration (as far as I know!) They each have their strengths and weaknesses, depending on what you want them to do. For example, it would be wrong to say that the Lebesgue integral is "better" than the Riemann integral; there are definitely many natural problems where the simplicity of Riemann far outweighs the generality of Lebesgue (e.g. contour integration in Complex Analysis, integration of continuous Banach space-valued functions).

So, I think you have to be more specific about what you want integrals for.

Comment: Incidentally, and picking up on @Zen Harper's comment: on R, say, there are Riemann-integrable functions that are not Lebesgue integrable. For example, Riemann integration allows for "conditionally convergent" integrals that Lebesgue integration disallows. A theory that is strictly stronger than both (but doesn't generalize well to manifolds) is called "gauge integration" (nothing to do with what the physicists call "gauge integration"). A function is Lebesgue-integrable iff it is absolutely gauge-integrable, and every (even improper) Riemann-integrable function is (properly) gauge-integrable.

Comment: @Theo: To define “conditionally convergent” Riemann integrals you have to perform one additional step, namely, you have to pass to a limit with respect to the length of the interval.  You might as well perform this step after Lebesgue integration and obtain “conditionally convergent” Lebesgue integrals.

Answer (score 19):

Here is my own favorite construction of the (Lebesgue) integral.

Suppose M is an arbitrary smooth manifold.
Denote by Or(M) the orientation line bundle of M.
This bundle is equipped with a canonical Riemannian metric.
Vectors of length 1 in the fiber of Or(M) over a point p∈M correspond canonically to the two orientations
of the tangent space at the point p.
The manifold M is orientable if and only if the bundle Or(M) is trivializable.
Choosing an orientation of M amounts to choosing an isometric trivialization of Or(M).

The bundle Or(M) together with its natural metric is flat.
Hence we can twist the de Rham complex Ω^0(M)→⋯→Ω^n(M)
by Or(M) and obtain the following *twisted de Rham complex*: Ω^0(M)⊗Or(M)→⋯→Ω^n(M)⊗Or(M).
(Here by a complex I mean a complex of sheaves.)
The line bundle Ω^n(M)⊗Or(M) is called the *bundle of densities* and is denoted by Dens(M).
This bundle has a canonical orientation (hence it is trivializable), but does not have a canonical
metric or a canonical trivialization.

The cohomology of the twisted de Rham complex (with compact support) is called the *twisted de Rham cohomology* (with compact support).
We have a canonical map C^∞_cs(Dens(M))→H^n_cs(M,Or(M)).
Here C^∞_cs is the space of global sections of a vector bundle with compact support
and H^n_cs denotes the nth cohomology with compact support.

The Poincaré duality gives us a canonical isomorphism H^n_cs(M,Or(M))→H_0(M).
Finally, the map from M to the point induces a map in homology H_0(M)→H_0(∙)=R.

The composition of maps C^∞_cs(Dens(M))→H^n_cs(M,Or(M))→H_0(M)→H_0(∙)=R
gives us a map ∫: C^∞_cs(Dens(M))→R, which is the integration map.
Note that the actual integration (over each connected component) happens
in the first map.
The second map is an isomorphism and the third map simply sums integrals over individual connected components.

The map f∈C^∞_cs(Dens(M))→∫|f|∈[0,∞) is a norm on C^∞_cs(Dens(M)).
Completing C^∞_cs(Dens(M)) in this norm yields L_1(M)(=L^1(M)), which
can be identified with the space of finite complex-valued measures on M.

The space of bounded measurable functions on M (=L_0(M)=L^∞(M)) can be constructed by completing C^∞(M) in the σ-weak topology induced by L_1(M).
Other L_p spaces can be constructed in a similar way to L_1(M) by completing
sections of the bundle of p-densities instead of the bundle of 1-densities Dens(M).

The development of the remainder of measure theory in this approach largely parallels
the one explained in [one of my previous answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical-p/20820#20820).

I want to stress that these constructions do not rely on any existing integration theory.
In fact, they can be used to build integration theory on smooth manifolds from scratch
without ever referring to the usual measure theory with its lengthy and technical proofs.

**Added later:** In the middle of the proof, we relied on Poincaré duality, which can be most easily established using sheaf cohomology.
To this end, one must show that the de Rham cohomology is isomorphic to the sheaf cohomology with real coefficients.
This boils down immediately to the Poincaré lemma.

The simplest way to establish the Poincaré lemma is as follows.
The de Rham complex of a finite-dimensional smooth manifold M
is the free C^∞-dg-ring on the C^∞-ring C^∞(M).
If M is the underlying smooth manifold of a finite-dimensional
real vector space V, then C^∞(M) is the free C^∞-ring on
the vector space V* (the real dual of V).
Thus, the de Rham complex of a finite-dimensional real vector space V
is the free C^∞-dg-ring on the vector space V*.
This free C^∞-dg-ring is the free C^∞-dg-ring on the free cochain
complex on the vector space V*.
The latter cochain complex is simply V*→V* with the identity differential.
It is cochain homotopy equivalent to the zero cochain complex,
and the free functor from cochain complexes to C^∞-dg-rings
preserves cochain homotopy equivalences.
Thus, the de Rham complex of the smooth manifold V
is cochain homotopy equivalent to the free C^∞-dg-ring on
the zero cochain complex, i.e., **R** in degree 0.

Comment: So you are discarding the lengthy and technical proofs in measure
theory in favour of Poincare duality.

So, how does one construct the duality isomorphism
$H^n_c(M,\mathbb{Or}(M))\to H_0(M)$ (presumably with real
coefficients) without integration? I'd appreciate any
hints/references (even if just for the case $M=\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @Robin: For example, see the proof of Poincaré duality in Hatcher's textbook (Section 3.3).  It does not use integration.

Comment: Neither does Hatcher's proof use de Rham cohomology.

Comment: @Robin: As you might know, the de Rham cohomology is canonically isomorphic to the singular cohomology with real coefficients.

Comment: So I should amend my original statement to "So, you are
discarding the lengthy and technical proofs in measure
theory in favour of Poincare duality **and** the de Rham theorem".
(It is fortunate that these have short and non-technical proofs :-)).

Alas, the proof of de Rham's theorem I have come closest
to understanding is that in Warner's book. He relies on Poincare's
Lemma (for the proof that the sheafified de Rham complex is exact)
and for that he uses integration :-(

Comment: @Robin: Of course, integration is one way to prove Poincaré's lemma, but certainly not the only one.

Comment: @Robin: Also, I do not agree with this “in favor of“ ideology.  Proofs in measure theory can hardly be useful for anything else.  On the other hand, Poincaré duality and de Rham theorem have independent value.

Comment: I don't understand the emphasis on measure theory: suppose we stick to differential forms version of the de Rham theory, then the corresponding notion of integral is "Riemann integral on manifolds". What I'd like to know is what proof of the Poincaré lemma doesn't use integration!

Comment: Me too, Victor :-)
I don't understand this anti-measure theory ideology either.
I'm the first to want to avoid lengthy and technical proofs
('cos I can't understand them), but I prefer not to replace them
with even more lengthy and even more technical proofs. :-)

Comment: An integration-free proof of Poincare duality can be found in section 3.1 here:

http://www.math.uni-muenster.de/u/lueck/publ/lueck/ictp.pdf

The idea is to first prove Poincare duality abstractly (i.e. for topological manifolds) and then use Hodge theory (which I *think* is integration-free) to bring differential forms into the picture.  It may seem a little perverse to define integration via Hodge theory, but on the other hand surgery theory seems to tell us the Hodge theory is deeply relevant to smooth manifold theory (via the signature theorem).

Comment: What does this *proof* or *strategy* do in the case where M=(0,1) or [0,1] or the circle?

Comment: Count me in as interested in a integration-free proof of Poincare's lemma for de Rham cohomology. Integration exhibits a particular form in terms of the smooth contraction map. An alternative existence proof would have to be non-constructive. Maybe you can rephrase it as an existence problem for an associated Laplacian when the set is geodesically convex, cf. Paul's suggestion of Hodge theory?

Comment: @Victor: Measure theory = integration theory.  @Robin: There is no “anti-measure theory ideology” in my answer.  I just point out that measure theory for smooth manifolds can be developed much more easily (modulo existing tools) than in the standard approach (modulo existing tools).

Comment: Here is one way to prove Poincaré's lemma without integration for a finite-dimensional real inner product space V.  Observe that the lemma is true for polynomial forms.  Now consider the complete nuclear space of all smooth k-forms equipped with the natural topology.  The subspaces of exact forms and closed forms are closed in this topology.  The subspace of all polynomial closed forms is dense in the subspace of all closed forms.  Every polynomial closed form is also exact, hence the subspace of exact forms contains the closure of the subspace of polynomial closed forms.

Comment: Hmm... There are some issues with this argument. Consider the following "lemma": only constant function is equal to its own derivative. Observe that the lemma is true for polynomial functions. Now consider the complete nuclear space of smooth functions equipped with the natural topology. The subspace of functions equal to its own derivatives and zero subspace are closed in this topology. Every polynomial function that is equal to its own derivative is zero, hence zero subspace contains the closure of the subspace of polynomial functions equal to its own derivative. Have we proved the lemma?

Comment: @Victor: The space of polynomial functions that are equal to their own derivative is not dense in the space of all functions that are equal to their own derivative.

Comment: @Paul Siegel: "use Hodge theory (which I think is integration-free)" Nope, take a look at an arbitrary textbook.

Comment: @Johannes: The fact that some textbooks use integration to develop Hodge theory does not imply that you cannot develop Hodge theory without integration.

Comment: @Dmititri: well, in terms of logic, you are of course right. But the fact is that ALL textbooks I know (around 20 texts) make heavy use of Lebesgue integration theory (or quote the main technical result, or do not say anything specific about the theory).
Where, exactly, can I read about an "integration-free" approach to the basic result of Hodge theory, i.e. the statement that each cohomology class (under the known assumptions) has a unique harmonic representative?? 

Comment: @Dmitri: "The subspaces of exact forms and closed forms are closed in this topology". Both statements are true, one proof is trivial, the other one isn't. How do I see that the space of exact forms is closed?

Comment: @Johannes: You can easily derive Hodge theory from the elliptic regularity theorem.  If you prove the latter without integration, you obtain an integration-free exposition of Hodge theory.  However, I prefer to develop integration first, then prove the elliptic regularity theorem.

Comment: @Johannes: The nuclear space of forms is complete, therefore the closure of the subspace of exact forms is isomorphic to its completion.  Thus the space of exact forms is closed if and only if it is complete.  The space of (k+1)-exact forms is isomorphic to the space of k-forms modulo closed k-forms as a topological vector space (a consequence of the open mapping theorem).  Closed k-forms form a closed subspace of the complete nuclear space of k-forms, therefore the factor space is complete.

Comment: @Dmitri: "You can easily derive Hodge theory from the elliptic regularity theorem". This is how it is done. Elliptic regularity, however, is the problem. "However, I prefer to develop integration first, then prove the elliptic regularity theorem": so do I, but I do not think this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Dmitri: the open mapping theorem has an assumption: completeness of the target.

Comment: @Johannes: No, the open mapping theorem requires only the domain of the map to be complete, the completeness of the codomain is implied by the theorem.  Reference: Theorem I.3.1 in Bourbaki's Topological Vector Spaces.

Comment: @Dmitri: Bourbaki, loc. cit.: "Soient E et F deux espaces vectoriels metrisables et complets sur un corps value non discret K. Toute application lineaire continue u de E sur F est un homomorphisme". "homomorphisme"=open linear continuous map, "sur": surjective, "complet"=complete. Otherwise, any operator from a complete source would have a complete image, which is absurd.

Comment: @Johannes: Perhaps you are referring to one of the older editions of Bourbaki.  I use the 1987 English translation, which says “Let E and F be two metrisable vector spaces over a non-discrete valued division ring K, and let u be a continuous linear mapping of E in F.  Suppose that E is complete.  Then the following conditions are equivalent: (i) u is a strict surjective morphism.  (ii) F is complete and u is surjective.  (iii) The image of u is not meagre in F (GT, IX, § 5.2).  (iv) For every neighbourhood V of 0 in E, the set \overline{u(V)} is a neighbourhood of 0 in F.”

Comment: @Dmitri: but you need to read this with care. I do not have the English edition here, but the word "strict" means something, probably to the effect that u is a quotient map tom its image. Consider a map of Banach spaces u: E \to F, injective, dense image, but not surjective. Examples abund. Im(u) has two norms, the quotient norm (in which it is complete since E is complete) and the restriction of the norm of F (in which Im(u) is not complete since it is not closed in F). u is strict if you consider the first norm, but it is not strict in the second norm, because that would lead to the.

Comment: absurd conclusion that Im(u) is complete, hence closed in F. You can apply the open mapping theorem to show that Im(u) is closed in F if you know that the quotient and subspace topology are equivalent. 

Comment: @Johannes: What I meant is that you should use the fourth criterion in the above list.  However, the proof seems to be more technical than Schapiro's proof combined with the proof of surjectivity of differentiation via Lagrange's theorem, therefore I suggest we stick to the latter proof.

Comment: Just seen this. Dmitri, are you planning to write up your answer and your various claims in this comment thread in a more formal form (either as an expository article or as part of your thesis)? I would be interested to read this, although currently I share some of Johannes' qualms - if you don't know a priori that a chain complex of Frechet spaces is exact (when regarded as a complex of vector spaces) then it is not true that the "spaces of boundaries" are always closed in "the spaces of cycles", at least not without additional justification/hypotheses.

Comment: Afterthought: I really think it would help if you were a little less strident in your promotion of (NC)geometric ideas, topics and toolkits above all else. Not *everything* has to be geared towards Doing Better Geometry, surely?

Comment: Finally: I think it is far from obvious that this "construction of the Lebesgue integral" is non-circular. I am not saying that it is, but the various dualities and completions you rely on as you move through the argument in your answer and in some of your comments need independent justification; this is why I would be interested to see a fuller account written up (at some future date).

Comment: @Yemon: This stuff is too elementary to be included in my thesis, but I might write it up at some point, perhaps as a blog post.  I agree that addtional arguments are required to justify the claim.

Comment: @Yemon: I do not think that the word “strident” justly describes the situation here.  The question asked for the “correct natural definition of the integral from a non-analytic point of view” and I suggested one.  In general, every mathematical theory should be developed in the right context.  Theories like integration on smooth manifolds, general topology, and measure theory were first developed as a part of analysis but now we realize that the proper context for them is different.

Comment: @Dmitri: OK, thanks, especially for the last comment. (For what it's worth I learned a large chunk of my functional analysis without any measure theory, by dealing with completions of various normed spaces; but I had to learn the rudiments of measure theory during a course in (rigorous) probability theory. So I have an ambivalent attitude towards it myself.)

Comment: [admin note: I just rolled back a "Let's put LaTeX in something four years old" edit, because IIRC Dmitri very deliberately avoids MathJax. If I misremembered, Dmitri, and you would like "LaTeX" formatting, then please let us know]

Comment: and rolled back **again** ...

Comment: @YemonChoi: Many thanks for your efforts.  I very much like TeX formatting, but not if it takes several minutes to process…

Comment: @DmitriPavlov have you by any chance written up the details of an integration-free construction? I (and surely many others) would love to learn it.

Comment: @Arrow: Additional details appear here in the comments: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43681/motivating-the-de-rham-theorem/43706#43706

Answer (score 16):

As the others have mentioned, integration over a connected oriented smooth manifold $M$ can be characterized (modulo some technicalities) according to the fact that it fits into an exact sequence:

$\Omega_c^{n-1}(M) \to \Omega_c^n(M) \to \mathbb{R} \to 0$

where $\Omega_c^*$ refers to the De Rham complex, the first arrow is the De Rham differential, and the second arrow is integration.  In particular, $\int_M$ defines an isomorphism $H^n(M^n) \to \mathbb{R}$.  This line of thinking leads to Poincare duality: if one takes a submanifold $V$ representing a dimension $p$ homology class of $M$ (this is always possible *ratianally*) then the integration isomorphism determines a dimension $p$ cohomology class $[\omega]$, and this can be paired with a cohomology class $[\eta]$ in dimension $n-p$ via the exterior product (cup product):

$([\omega],[\eta]) \mapsto \int_M \omega \wedge \eta$

Poincare duality is precisely the assertion that this pairing is nondegenerate.  I think this point of view on integration - as a pairing between homology and cohomology - leads to many of the genuinely non-analytic formulations of integration.

---

Still, I would not consider this to have the final say as the correct natural definition of integration.  For one thing, manifolds are far from the only spaces that one could want to integrate over, and I highly doubt integration has a cohomological formulation in any serious generality beyond manifolds.  Second, the theory of measures truly is fundamental to integration and should be involved in an essential way; dynamical systems people often care as much about the measure as they do the integral.

Here is what I think integration is all about.  Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space (this is enough generality for the vast majority of applications of integration that I know of) and consider the space $C_0(X)$ of continuous functions on $X$ vanishing at infinity (in the sense of the one-point compactification).  Whatever intuition you have about integration, it must tell you that the integral should be a way of assigning a real number to a continuous function (maybe other functions too) which depends linearly on the function.  In other words, it has to be some sort of linear functional on $C_0(X)$.  Of course, not every linear functional deserves to be called an integral - if $x \in X$ then $f \mapsto f(x)$ is a linear functional on $C_0(X)$, but it doesn't make much sense to call it an "integral".

So we allow the topology of $X$ to play a greater role.  Recall that $C_0(X)$ is a Banach space if it is equipped with the uniform norm, and as such it comes equipped with a preferred collection of linear functionals: the set $C_0(X)^*$ of continuous linear functionals.  If we pretend for a moment that we have already worked really hard and built the theory of integration with respect to a Borel measure $\mu$, then assuming the measure is tied closely enough to the topology of $X$ (precisely, it must be a "Radon measure") we would have a continuous linear functional $I_\mu$ on $C_0(X)$ given by $I_\mu(f) = \int f d\mu$.

Riesz Representation Theorem: Let $M(X)$ denote the Banach space of Radon measures on $X$. The map $M(X) \mapsto C_0(X)^*$ given by $\mu \mapsto I_\mu$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Consequently, if we hadn't already invented a notion of integration it would be perfectly possible to simply define $\int_X f d\mu$ to be $I_\mu(f)$.  I personally think this is the right way to think about integrals.

Comment: One more thing.  You might be interested in the following note:

http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~tl/glasgowpssl/banach.pdf

if you would like the Lebesgue integral to appear more natural (in more ways than one).  While the punchline may seem profound at first, there isn't actually much serious content.

Comment: I don't know much about the work of Jenny Harrison, but I think that she does have a theory of differential forms, etc., for quite non-smooth spaces.  I could be wrong, though; if you (or another reader here) know(s) her work, maybe you can comment on it?

Comment: I'm at best marginally familiar with Harrison's work as well, but in my experience calculus over non-smooth spaces generally only works almost everywhere relative to some measure.  In particular it requires additional assumptions (e.g. curvature bounds in the sense of Alexandrov geometry) and hard work to prove theorems about the topology of non-smooth spaces.  Harrison's techniques are different from what I'm used to though, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 11):

If you are interested in manifolds, then you might be interested in various related notions of *measures* and *distributions*.  Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with algebra of functions $C^\infty(M)$.  There is a very general notion of a *distribution*, which is that of any linear function $C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb R$.  In this framework, a distribution is a *measure* if it satisfies a positivity condition, namely that it takes everywhere-nonnegative functions to nonnegative numbers.

Another, different definition of "distribution" corresponds to the *distribution bundle on $M$*, which is a canonical trivializable line bundle on $M$.  It can be presented by gluing data and transition amplitudes as follows.  Let $U,V \subseteq M$ with $\phi: U \to \mathbb R^n$ and $\psi: V \to \mathbb R^n$ be coordinate charts, and consider the trivial bundles one-dimensional bundles over $U,V$.  We glue them together by giving transition data: if $f$ is a section over $U$ of the trivial bundle, on $U\cap V$ we identify it with the section $f \cdot \left| \det \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \psi}\right|$ of the trivial bundle over $V$.  (When $M$ is oriented, this bundle is the same as the *determinant bundle* $\wedge^{\operatorname{top}} {\rm T}^*M$; the determinant bundle is always a line bundle, and so its square is trivializable, and has a trivializable square root, which is the distribution line bundle whether $M$ is oriented or not.)  Note that the transition functions preserve positivity of the sections, and so the notion of "positive distribution" and so on are well-defined.

Finally, if you are interested in a totally algebraic notion of integration for $\mathbb R^n$, you might be interested in the following observation, which in some form is older but nevertheless deserves to be called an observation of Berezin.  Namely, the *integral*, as a linear map $C^\infty_{\operatorname{compact}}(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb R$, is uniquely defined up to scalar multiple by the fact that it vanishes on the images of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} : C^\infty_{\operatorname{compact}}(\mathbb R^n) \to C^\infty_{\operatorname{compact}}(\mathbb R^n)$.  Here $C^\infty_{\operatorname{compact}}(\mathbb R^n)$ is the algebra of smooth functions with compact support, and $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are the usual coordinate functions on $\mathbb R^n$.  There are many situations in which by naming an algebra "of functions" and some "partial derivatives" you can uniquely (up to scalar) determine an "integral".  An example is the algebra of de Rham differential forms on an oriented manifolds $M$, and the "partial derivatives" are the de Rham $d$ and the Lie derivatives for all vector fields on $M$.  This <strike>uniquely</strike> picks out the integral that is zero on non-top forms and integrates top forms over $M$ as a canonical "measure" on the "space" whose "algebra of functions" is the differential forms.  This is an example of a "superintegral", and it was to motivate a definition of superintegrals that Berezin made the above observation.

Comment: This only allows us to integrate smooth functions with compact support, right?

Comment: I really like the observation of Berezin!  Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Harry: As I explain in my answer, you can easily complete the space of functions with compact support to the space of all integrable functions.  Of course, not every smooth function with non-compact support is integrable.

Comment: @Vivek: The observation of Berezin is also known as Poincaré duality.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Without knowing anything about these matters I am a little weirded out that you define a distribution to be *any* linear map $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M) \to \mathbb{R}$. Do you not need any continuity assumptions with respect to some appropriate topology? And do you assume *M* compact? If not, the constant function 1 will not even define a distribution in this sense unless you replace $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ with, say, the algebra of compactly supported smooth functions.

Comment: @Dan: Of course you have to use some topology and of course $C_c^\infty(M)$ is the space on is interested in. If you use test functions with compact support, you'll get all distributions. If you use all smooth test functions, then you'll only get the distributions with compact support.

Comment: One can also view Berezin's observation as an infinitesimal version of the observation that Lebesgue measure is the (unique up to constants) Haar measure on R^n.  (If a measure is translation invariant, then it will annihilate derivatives with respect to infinitesimal translations, i.e. partial derivatives.)  To me, this is one of the most natural definitions of Lebesgue measure, though it probably does not qualify as "non-analytic" in the sense you are looking for.



Comment: @Terry Tao: yes, precisely. And I should emphasize that I'm not a historian; I think that the fact that Lebesgue measure is the unique translation-invariant measure (up to scalar) is older than Berezin, but that it's Berezin who proposed to use this observation to generalize to a more algebraic treatment of integration. @Dan Petersen: I was being sloppy. There are, to my mind, different good notions of "distribution". There are some that let you integrate any smooth function, some for any continuous function with compact support, etc.

Comment: @Vivek: I haven't read Berezin's original papers.  For the theory of super integration, the book by Voronov, if memory serves, is decent, but I don't have it handy to check.  Alternately, I think that Deligne and Mumford's chapter in QFT for Mathematicians describes super integration.

Comment: @Terry: Is there a version of the characterization-as-Haar measure which gives the global "integral over a manifold" as the "annihilator of de Rham d & lie derivatives wrt. all vector fields"? 

Comment: BTW: I think I was too cavalier, by which I means sloppy.  There certainly can be more than one dimension worth of linear functionals out of the algebra of differential forms (with compact support) that vanish on exact forms and on all Lie derivatives.  In particular, if the manifold is disconnected, I could rescale all forms on one of the pieces by whatever constant I want.

Answer (score 6):

My answer here is realy just a footnote to Paul Siegel's excellent answer, but it has become too long to fit in a comment box. Integrals are siamese brothers to measures; leaving them out seems rather perverse to me. Anyway, here is how I think of integrals. The objective here is to tackle the "categorical" part; the analytical viewpoint will necessarily obtrude. But bear with me a little, this is a somewhat long post, with a punchline at the end.

Fix a Boolean algebra $\Omega$. A map $\nu: \Omega\to V$ with values on a linear space $V$ is finitely additive if $\nu(E\cup F)= \nu(E) + \nu(F)$ for every disjoint $E, F$. Denote the linear space of such maps by $\mathbf{A}(\Omega, V)$.

Theorem 1: There is a linear space $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$ and a finitely additive map $\chi:\Omega\to \mathbf{S}(\Omega)$ universal among all finitely additive maps.
proof: just follow the universal property and do the obvious thing (yeah, I suppose you can use the adjoint functor theorem but why would you?).

The universal property recast in terms of representability gives the natural isomorphism ($\mathbf{Vect}$ is the category of linear spaces)

$$\mathbf{A}(\Omega, V)\cong \mathbf{Vect}(\mathbf{S}(\Omega), V)$$

Before continuing, let me elucidate a little bit of the structure of $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$.

Theorem 2: Let $f$ be a non-zero element of $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$. Then there are non-zero scalars $k_n$ and non-zero, pairwise disjoint $E_n\in \Omega$ such that $f= \sum_n k_n\chi(E_n)$. Furthermore, if $\nu$ is a finitely additive map and $\widehat{\nu}$ the map induced on $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$ by universality, then $\widehat{\nu}(f)= \sum_{n}k_n \nu(E_n)$.

To put it simply, $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$ is the linear space of "simple functions on $\Omega$" and the map induced by universality is the integral. Now use theorem 2 to put a norm on $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$:

$$\|\sum_n k_n\chi(E_n)\|= \max\{|k_n|\}$$

Denote the completion by $\mathbf{L}_{\infty}(\Omega)$. On the other hand, put on the linear subspace of the *bounded* finitely additive maps $\Omega\to B$ with $B$ a Banach space, the semivariation norm (which I am not going to define). Denote this space by $\mathbf{BA}(\Omega, B)$. Then:

Theorem 3: There is a bounded finitely additive $\chi:\Omega\to \mathbf{L}_{\infty}(\Omega)$ universal among all bounded finitely additive maps.

Once again, recasting the universal property in terms of representability, we have a natural isometric isomorphism ($\mathbf{Ban}$ is the category of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps).

$$\mathbf{BA}(\Omega, B)\cong \mathbf{Ban}(\mathbf{L}_{\infty}(\Omega), B)$$

It is illuminating to write down what does the naturality of the isomorphism implies: I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Note that $\mathbf{L}_{\infty}(\Omega)$ is a Banach algebra in a natural way (use theorem 2 or juggle the universal property around. Or "cheat" all the way up and use Stone duality) and that $\chi$ is *spectral* or *multiplicative*, that is, $\chi(E\cap F)= \chi(E)\chi(F)$. Theorem 3 can now be extended by saying that $\chi$ is universal among all spectral measures (with values in Banach algebras). This extension is trivial given theorem 3.

The case of $\mathbf{L}_{\infty}(\Omega)$ does not need the introduction of measures but of course, this is not so with $\mathbf{L}_{1}$. So fix a finitely additive, positive $\mu:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$. For the sake of simplification I will assume $\mu$ non-degenerate, that is, $\mu(E)= 0$ implies $E= 0$ (otherwise, you will have to take some quotient along the way). A finitely additive $\nu:\Omega\to B$ with $B$ a Banach space is $\mu$-Lipschitz if there is a constant $C$ such that $\|\nu(E)\|\leq C\mu(E)$ for all $E$. The infimum of all the constants $C$ in the conditions of the inequality gives a norm and a normed space I will denote by $\mathbf{LA}(\Omega, \mu, B)$. On the other hand, endow $\mathbf{S}(\Omega)$ with the norm

$$\|\sum_n k_n\chi(E_n)\|= \sum_n |k_n|\mu(E_n)$$

and denote the completion by $\mathbf{L}_{1}(\Omega, \mu)$.

Theorem 4: There is a finitely additive, $\mu$-Lipschitz $\chi:\Omega\to \mathbf{L}_{1}(\Omega, \mu)$ universal among all such maps.

Before the conclusion let me address a few points.

1. Measurable spaces are not needed. If you really want them, use Stone duality (that is, points count for nothing in measure theory so why not leave them out, heh?).
2. Finitely additive measures are really not that much more general than $\sigma$-additive ones. I will leave this cryptic comment as is, and just note that once again, Stone duality is the key here.
3. I am *not* advocating this approach to be used in teaching (unless your goal is to flunk and befuddle as many undergrads as humanly possible). For one, you need some functional analysis under the belt (Banach spaces, completions, semivariation, etc.). Intuition is very hard to come by as I have thrown away the measurable spaces without which THE most important example, Lebesgue measure (arguably, the core of a first measure theory course) cannot be constructed. The whole logic of the approach only makes sense after you have seen other instances of categorical thinking at work. I am sure you can think of other objections.

How categorical is this approach? Certainly, the universal properties of the respective spaces are central to the whole business and at least, they make clear that some results are really just a consequence of abstract nonsense. In the words of P. Freyd, category theory is doing what it was invented for: to make the easy things really easy (or some such, my memory is lousy). For example, the Bochner vector integral is obtained simply by taking the projective tensor product. Fubini and Fubini-Tonelli on the equality of iterated integrals are other notable cases of categorical thinking at work. Now pepper with Stone duality and a few more tools (e.g. Hahn-Banach and the compact-Hausdorff monad) and you can get (a slight variation of) the Riesz representation theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces. Use the proper compactifications and generalize to wider classes of topological spaces. Or use Loomis-Sikorski to get Vitali-Hahn-Saks in one line (but this is really "cheating" as the crucial step in establishing Loomis-Sikorski is essentially the same as the one to establish Vitali-Hahn-Saks: a Baire category-theorem application). And a few more.

But once again, how categorical is this approach? Well, the argument is categorical enough to be generalized to symmetric monoidal closed categories. See R. Borger -- A categorical approach to integration, in the 23rd volume of TAC available online. For the modifications needed to internalize the arguments to a topos (and much more) see the delightful Phd thesis of Mathew Jackson "A Sheaf theoretic approach to measure theory" -- this is available online, just google for it. Oh, by the way, you can see (almost) everything I have explained above in volume 3 of D. Fremlin's measure theory 5-volume series, also available online.

Comment: My own hazy recollection is that Freyd's aphorism was along the following lines: "category theory performs the service of showing that trivially true things are trivially true for trivial reasons." I'm sure someone can come along to correct us.

Comment: I really like this presentation of the ideas, since the more compressed versions I've seen presented or alluded to are harder for Bears of Little Brain like myself to follow. Moreover, by going into detail and not just waving some big representability theorem, this pre-empts fears/suspicions of circularity in constructions.

Comment: Link for the Boerger article: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/23/12/23-12abs.html