# De Rham isomorphism without integration?

Tags: differential-topology

Is it possible to prove the de Rham isomorphism between de Rham cohomology groups and singular cohomology with coefficients in the reals without resorting to any form of integration?

It seems remotely possible to me, but on the other hand, having deRham isomorphism, we can define integration by using Poincare duality $H^{n}(M, \mathbb{R}) \simeq H^{0}(M, \mathbb{R})$, because for connected manifolds we have $H^{0}(M, \mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R}$ in a canonical way.

One imagines it could be possible *in principle* because one can prove that any cohomology theory $E^{\bullet}$ (on, let's say, pairs of CW-complexes) that has the same coefficients as singular cohomology is necessarily isomorphic to it. We prove it by considering the cellular complex associated to the skeletal filtration

$X_{0} \subseteq \ldots \subseteq X_{n} \subseteq \ldots \subseteq X$

with respect to $E^{\bullet}$. Then because $E^{\bullet}$ has exactly the same coefficients as singular cohomology, this complex will be isomorphic to the usual cellular complex.

There are a number of obstructions to this approach for de Rham cohomology. Indeed, one should find a good replacement of the skeletal filtration of a CW-complex, something like "filtration with submanifolds". Also, it is not at all clear to me what is the right definition of de Rham cohomology on "pairs of manifolds".

I hope my question is not too trivial for MathOverflow.

Comment: It is a corollary of the de Rham isomorphism that every function on the line has an antiderivative. How could you prove that without integration?

Comment: I think that on this site, Dmitri Pavlov has left some answers which preach an approach similar to what you are after. It is not clear to me, however, that he avoids circularity

Comment: Isn't this what sheaf theory was born to do?! Both the de Rham complex and resolution by the sheaf of singular cochains are resolutions of the constant sheaf which are acyclic for global sections, and hence both compute the cohomology of the constant sheaf.

Comment: I think that Tom's comment is *the* answer. 
(Checking the  de Rham resolution is a resolution of the constant sheaf would require
the Poincar\'e lemma, and hence integration. I don't see it can be avoided.)

Comment: I don't see how one can avoid integration.    Philosophically speaking, I view cohomology as a local-to-global mechanism.  Integration  is  yet another local-to-global  mechanism. The fact that two such mechanism   touch in some places ought not be a surprise.

Comment: @Donu: Yes, of course you are right ... 

Comment: @Yemon: I had a heated discussion with Dmitri here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43681/motivating-the-de-rham-theorem/43730#43730.
In the end, he could cook up a quite involved argument for the Poincare lemma that avoided the explicit use of the integral. His claim, that the Lebesgue integral can be constructed by this is, however, totally unclear to me.


Comment: For a purist with integral-phobia, there are some more obstructions to overcome, even if you take the Poincare lemma as god-given. 
It seems unclear to me how to prove that manifolds are homotopy equivalent to CW complexes or have good covers without the construction techniques of differential topology, which rely on two pillars, both deeply connected to calculus: Sards Theorem and the existence of solutions of ODEs.


Comment: About the existence of antiderivatives on the real line - I understand that this seems impossible, but it doesn't actually say that it is. This is why I asked this question.

Comment: Antiderivatives can be easily constructed without integration: we can compute antiderivatives of polynomials algebraically and then observe that the resulting operation is continuous and polynomials are dense in all functions (Weierstrass' theorem for C^0, Lagrange's theorem for C^k and C^∞).  This can (not necessarily “should” or “must”) be used to define integrals of smooth densities on smooth manifolds using the Poincaré duality and prove the de Rham isomorphism.

Comment: @Johannes: yes, I remember that discussion. @Dmitri: when you "observe that antidifferentiation of polynomials is continuous", how are you proposing to do this? The polynomial approximants may converge as functions on a specified interval without uniform term-by-term convergence (otherwise continuous functions would automatically admit real-analytic extension)

Comment: @Yemon: We only need continuity in C^k topology on any interval for finite k.

Comment: @Dmitri: I'm not sure that you have answered my question. The C^k topology is usually defined by some variant of sup norms of derivatives. How are you going to show that if a sequence of polynomials, viewed as functions on the interval, converge to zero in this norm, then the antiderivatives form a Cauchy sequence in this norm?

Comment: @Yemon: Being small in the C^k topology means that the first k+1 derivatives are small in the supremum norm.  The derivatives of nonzero order are small because the original function was small in the C^k topology.  The derivative of order 0 (i.e., the antiderivative of the original function) is small because of Lagrange's theorem (the value at any point is the derivative at some intermediate point times the length of the interval).