# If $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, is its dual dense in $L^2(H)$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, measure-theory, banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional, separable Hilbert space, and let $\gamma$ be a Radon probability measure on $H$ with mean zero and covariance operator the identity $I$.

Let $H^*$ denote the space of continuous linear functionals on $H$.  By the Riesz representation theorem, $$H^* = \{ \langle k, \cdot \rangle : k \in H \}.$$  By the assumption that $\gamma$ has covariance operator $I$, for all $k \in H$, $$\int_H |\langle k, h \rangle|^2 \, \mathrm{d}\gamma(h) = \langle k, k \rangle < \infty,$$ so $H^*$ is contained in the [separable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46094/if-h-is-a-separable-hilbert-space-is-l2h-separable) Hilbert space $L^2(H)$.

**My question:**  Is $H^*$ dense in $L^2(H)$?

Comment: Certainly not when H is finite dimensional.

Comment: Does there exist such a measure for an infinite-dimensional $H$? There is surely no such Gaussian measure, for example.

Comment: Good point, Mark.  I've edited the question to include the assumption that $H$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: zhoraster, there does exist such a measure.  This is Corollary 2 in Section III.2.2 of <i>Probability Distributions on Banach Spaces</i> by Vakhania, Tarieladze and Chobanyan.  

Furthermore, there does exist a Gaussian measure with covariance operator $I$.  This is typical in the abstract Wiener space formalism for constructing Gaussian measures on Banach spaces.

Comment: The assumption here is that $\gamma$ is a weak-order two measure (i.e., `$H^* \subseteq L^2(H)$`).  You are correct that there exists no measure $\gamma$ under the assumption that it is of strong-order two, since $I$ is not Hilbert-Schmidt.

Comment: In general $|\langle \cdot, h\rangle|$ will not be in the closure of $H^*$.  Maybe you want to ask whether the polynomials in elements of $H^*$ are dense?

Comment: As I recall the construction, the Gaussian "measure" with covariance $I$ on a Hilbert space $H$ fails to be countably additive.  This is why you complete the space under a weaker norm.

Comment: Indeed, if such a Gaussian measure existed, let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H^*$; then $e_i$ are iid standard normal random variables.  But Bessel's inequality gives us $\sum e_i^2 < \infty$ a.s., which is absurd.

Comment: @Tom LaGatta: No, this ain't correct. A covariance operator of a Gaussian measure must be compact (even trace class).

Comment: @Tom LeGatta: I mean on a Hilbert space, naturally.

Comment: @Tom LeGatta: I've looked through comments and see what you mean now.

Comment: Bill:  Good point.

Nate and zhoraster:  You are correct, there is no such Gaussian measure.  There is the Gaussian cylinder set measure, which is not actually a measure for the reason that Nate described.  This has helped my understanding of what I actually need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Rewritten to give an answer more useful to future visitors.)

First of all, as noted in comments, there is no (countably additive) Gaussian measure on $H$ with covariance operator the identity.

However, if we take $\gamma$ to be some other Gaussian measure, the answer is no, $H^*$ is not dense in $L^2(H, \gamma)$.  One way to see this is that every $f \in H^*$, considered as a random variable on $(H, \gamma)$, has a centered Gaussian distribution (in which we include the "degenerate" Gaussian distribution which is the constant 0).  In particular $f$ has mean zero, and the mean-zero random variables are a proper closed subspace of $L^2(\gamma)$.  (So for instance, the nonzero constants are not in the closure of $H^*$.)

Indeed, $L^2$ limit of centered Gaussian random variables is again centered Gaussian (this actually holds if you replace "$L^2$" by "in distribution").  Thus every random variable in the $L^2$ closure of $H^*$ is centered Gaussian, and hence non-Gaussian $L^2$ functions on $H$ are not in the closure of $H^*$ either.

It is true that if you allow *polynomials* $F(x) = p(f_1(x), \dots, f_n(x))$ where $f_1, \dots, f_n \in H^*$, then all such functions $F$ are in $L^2(H,\gamma)$, and they form a dense subspace.  Indeed, if you let $p$ range over all Hermite polynomials of degree $n$, then the closed span of all corresponding $F$ gives you the space $\mathcal{H}_n$ which is the $n$th Wiener chaos, and we have an orthogonal decomposition $L^2(H, \gamma) = \bigoplus \mathcal{H}_n$.  These spaces are also the eigenspaces of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator $N$ (aka number operator).

Back to the "measure" with covariance operator $I$: we can consider such a "measure" as a finitely additive measure on the cylinder sets of $H$.  I suppose it might be possible to study an $L^2$ space with respect to this finitely additive measure.  I don't know much about such spaces, but I would guess that a similar argument would show that $H^*$ is still not dense.

Comment: So, for example, might a constant agree a.e. with a linear functional?


Comment: @GeraldEdgar As I have now explained more fully, no.  (Except for the constant 0, of course.)