# When is $L^{2}(X,\mathscr{B},m)$ spearable

Tags: measure-theory

If $X$ is a metric space, $m$ is a Borel probability space on $(X,\mathscr{B})$ where $\mathscr{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets on $X$, can we prove that the space　$L^{2}(X,\mathscr{B},m)$ is spearable?

Answer (score 2):

This post answers your question precisely: https://mathoverflow.net/a/42383.

I am not able to post this answer as a comment as I do not have 50 reputation yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have read the webpage you paste,but I have some difficulty in understanding. Would you like to give some more detail? Or recommend some related material.