# (non) separability of the power set

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose that $(X,2^X)$ is equipped with a non-atomic probability measure $\mu$ (the existence of such spaces is consistent with ZFC). This induces the $L_1$ pseudometric $\Delta$ on $2^X$, via 
$\Delta(A,B)=\mu((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Question: Assuming ZFC, does the (pseudo)metric space $(2^X,\Delta)$ contain an $\epsilon$-separated subset of cardinality at least $|X|$, for some $\epsilon>0$?

A subset $N$ of a metric space $(\Omega,\rho)$ is $\epsilon$-separated if for all $x,y\in N$ we have $\rho(x,y)>\epsilon$.

Comment: What does "uncountable" modify in "uncountable $\epsilon$-separated subsets"? Does it mean uncountably many pairs of subsets that are $\epsilon$-separated, or that the subsets themselves are uncountable? Additionally, when you say $\epsilon$-separated, do you mean "separated by at most $\epsilon$", or "separated by a nonzero amount that is at most $\epsilon$"?

Comment: Not necessarily - $\mu$ can be $\{0,1\}$-valued, in which case $\Delta$ has only two equivalence classes.

Comment: I've defined $\epsilon$-separated explicitly now. As for what "uncountable" refers to: it refers to the $\epsilon$-separated set $N$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, should've seen that one coming :)
I modified the question to exclude atoms.

Comment: I think $(2^X, \Delta)$ is separable iff $L^1(X,\mu)$ is separable, and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable shows that this happens only if the measure space is standard Borel - which such $X$ can't be.  But it seems like there should be a more direct way to show it.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think the same thing, and I saw that question you linked. I found the answers somewhat confusing (and partly contradictory), and was hoping to get the straight dope. Assuming I wanted to try going your route, what are some good starting pointers?

Comment: Yes. See M. Gitik, S. Shelah, Forcings with ideals and simple forcing notions -- Israel J Math 68 (1989) 129-160.

Comment: @Ashutosh It would be great if you could turn your comment into an answer -- which I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: @NateEldredge Although $L^1(X,\mu)$ is separable if $X$ is standard Borel and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, this is not a necessary condition, even for a Radon measure with support equal to $X$. Define $\mu$ to be a measure on the Borel sets of $X = \beta(\omega)$ such that $\mu(S)$ is the number of open points in $S$. This is a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure, and $L^1(X) \cong \ell^1(\omega)$, which is separable. However, standard Borel spaces have cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$, whereas $|\beta(\omega)| = 2^\mathfrak{c}$, so $\beta(\omega)$ is not standard Borel.

Comment: @RobertFurber: True.  Can we say that $X$ is the union of a standard Borel space and a null set?

Comment: @NateEldredge In my previous example, yes, but I don't think so in general. For instance, take $X$ to be the Stone space of the measure algebra of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. This admits a measure such that $L^1(X) \cong L^1([0,1])$. The general principle is if you have a $\sigma$-finite (or even just localizable) measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $X$, you can always define a measure $\nu$ on the Stone space $Y$ of the corresponding measure algebra of $(X,\mu)$ such that $L^1(Y,\nu) \cong L^1(X,\mu)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has a trivial negative answer, as long as an atomlessly measurable cardinal exists (if one doesn't it is vacuously true, of course). Given an atomless probability measure $\mu$ on $(Y, \mathcal{P}(Y))$, let $\lambda$ be the supremum of the cardinalities of the $\epsilon$-separated subsets of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$. We can then define $X = Y + \lambda^{+}$ and extend $\mu$ to $X$ by defining each subset of $\lambda^{+}$ to have measure 0. This is an atomless measure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, and any $\epsilon$-separated subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ defines an $\epsilon$-separated subset of $Y$ (by intersecting with $Y$, which doesn't change the measure). So there is no $\epsilon$-separated subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of cardinality $|X|$, because $|X| \geq \lambda^+ > \lambda$.

So I will reinterpret the question to give a more interesting positive answer, along the lines of what Ashutosh suggested, which is to say, $X$ will have atomlessly measurable cardinality $\kappa$, and $\mu : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow [0,1]$ will be the atomless $\kappa$-additive measure witnessing this fact. The material involved is adequately treated in [Fremlin's textbook](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mtcont.htm), though due to its size it is important to know where to look.

For any probability measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ we can form its *measure algebra*, $A = \Sigma/\mathcal{N}(\mu)$, where $\mathcal{N}(\mu)$ is the $\sigma$-ideal of sets $S \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(S) = 0$. That is to say, in $A$ we identify measurable sets up to null sets. For probability spaces, $A$ is a complete Boolean algebra.

The pseudometric $\Delta(A,B)$ in the question then becomes a metric on $A$, which Fremlin says is called the *measure metric* or *Fréchet-Nikodym metric* (323A (d)). Then in 521O (a) (ii), Fremlin shows that for a measure algebra whose underlying set is infinite, its density character $d(A)$ (the smallest cardinality of a dense subset) is equal to the  Maharam type of $A$, $\tau(A)$. The Maharam type of $A$ is the smallest cardinality of a subset of $A$ that generates $A$ as a complete Boolean algebra (331F).

By the Gitik-Shelah theorem (Theorem 2.6 in the reference provided by Ashutosh), for an atomless probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, $d(A) > \mathbf{add}(\mu)$, where $\mathbf{add}$ is the additivity. So in the setting described in the second paragraph, $\mathbf{add}(\mu) = \kappa$ by definition, so $d(A) > \kappa$. As $\kappa$ cannot be countable, this shows that $A$ cannot be separable (because separable spaces have $d(A) = \aleph_0$, by definition). This answers the question in the title.

But we still need to deal with the question of the $\epsilon$-separated subset. Given a cardinal $\kappa$, consider the space $2^\kappa$, as the compact product space of the discrete space $2$, and equip it with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the unique Radon probability measure $\nu_\kappa$ that treats $2^\kappa$ as a $\kappa$-indexed sequence of independent fair coins. For each $x \in \kappa$, define 
$$
C_x = \{ f \in 2^\kappa \mid f(x) = 0 \}
$$
Then it should be clear that if $x \neq y$ are elements of $\kappa$, $\Delta(C_x,C_y) = \frac{1}{2}$, so $(C_x)_{x \in \kappa}$ is a $\frac{1}{2}$-separated family of Borel subsets of $2^\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$. This will be important later. Also, we will use the notation $\mathfrak{B}_\kappa$ for the measure algebra of $(2^\kappa,\nu_\kappa)$, as Fremlin does.

Let's return to the measure algebra $A$ of $(X,\mu)$. By Maharam's classification (332B), $A \cong \prod_{i \in I}\mathfrak{B}_{\kappa_i}$, where $(\kappa_i)_{i \in I}$ is a countable family of cardinals, and under this isomorphism the measure $\mu$ is mapped to a suitable $\sigma$-convex combination of the measures $\nu_{\kappa_i}$, *i.e.* $\mu = \sum_{i \in I}\alpha_i \nu_{\kappa_i}$, where $\sum_{i \in I}\alpha_i = 1$ and $\alpha_i > 0$ for all $i \in I$. It is easy to show that 
$$
\tau(A) \leq \prod_{i \in I} \tau(\mathfrak{B}_{\kappa_i}) = \prod_{i \in I}\kappa_i
$$
(the fact that $\tau(\mathfrak{B}_{\kappa_i}) = \kappa_i$ is 331K in Fremlin).

We have that each $\kappa_i \leq \tau(A)$, and since the Gitik-Shelah theorem already mentioned (543F for the specific version in Fremlin's book) shows that $\tau(A) > \kappa$, and $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible, there must be an $i \in I$ such that $\kappa_i > \kappa = |X|$. As $\mathfrak{B}_{\kappa_i}$ embeds (non-unit-preservingly) as a subalgebra of $A$, the image of $(C_x)_{x \in \kappa_i}$ in $A$ is an $\epsilon = \frac{\alpha}{2}$-separated family of cardinality $\kappa_i > |X|$ in $A$, which gives rise to such a family in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by taking representatives of the equivalence classes.