# Diffusion processes in wide generality

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, measure-theory

It is common knowledge among schoolchildren that one may define jump diffusion processes in wide generality.

**Hard question:**  What are the most general structures on which one may define something which is appropriately called a jump diffusion process?

**Easier question:**  Can you define jump diffusions on Polish spaces?

I would love to see answers from both the [probabilistic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical-p/20828#20828) and [structuralist](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical-p/20820#20820) perspectives.