# Notation: Categories of measur(abl)e spaces

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, measure-theory, notation

Is there a common notation in the literature for

- the category of measurable spaces and measurable maps?
- the category of measure spaces and measure-preserving maps?

The nlab suggests $\mathsf{Measble}$ for the category of measurable spaces, but this looks a little bit ugly, and the nlab doesn't suggest something for the category of measure spaces. If there is no common notation, what is your suggestion? For example, $\mathsf{Meas}$ looks fine, but it is not clear a priori which category this should denote.

*Added.* According to the comments, $\mathsf{Meas}$ is a common notation for the category of measurable spaces and measurable maps. So what about the category of measure spaces? If there is no common notation:  What do you think about $\mathsf{MeasSp}$, $\mathsf{MeaSp}$, or $\mathsf{Measure}$? An argument for the latter: Rudin points out in his book on real and complex analysis that the whole information of a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is already encoded in the measure $\mu$, since $\mathcal{A}$ is the domain of $\mu$ and $\Omega$ is the greatest element of $\mathcal{A}$.

*Background.* I'm writing a text on category theory and thereby have found a nice example of a natural transformation: Consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ of measure spaces and measure-preserving maps and the category $\mathsf{Ban}$ of Banach spaces with non-expansive linear maps. Then $L^1 : \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Ban}$ is a functor and the integral provides us with a natural transformation $\int: L^1 \to \Delta(\mathbb{R})$. The naturality is precisely the [general transformation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_Change_of_variables_formula). Wouldn't it be nice to give $\mathcal{C}$ a unique name?
By the way, a similar natural transformation is used in Hartig's paper "The Riesz Representation Theorem Revisited" to give a conceptual proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem.

Comment: I have used the nLab's notation with disappointment for lack of a better alternative.

Comment: I'm familiar with *meas* for the first category. See for example [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089054010500204X).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks! The authors even say "This gives a category which is often called $\mathsf{Meas}$.". So it should be common. Have you seen a notation for the other category?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry, I haven't.

Comment: What do you think about $\mathsf{Measure}$ for the category of measure spaces (and $\mathsf{Meas}$ for the category of measurable spaces)?

Comment: I don't think there is any commonly used notation for these categories.  One reason for that might be that it's hard to do any nontrivial measure theory with these categories.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Thank you for your comment. I have found several papers on measure theory and probability theory which apply category theory to the categories of measurable resp. probability spaces. Do you say that it is hard to do nontrivial measure theory with *these* categories, but that it is possible for *other* categories, or that category theory is not useful for nontrivial measure theory at all? In the former case, I would like to know which alternative categories are more suitable.

Comment: How does this natural transf. relate to Tom Leinster's characterisation of Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The former.  When trying to prove any nontrivial theorem in measure theory (e.g., Riesz, Radon-Nikodym, etc.), one immediately runs into necessity of using null sets, so measurable spaces do not suffice.  On the other hand, measured spaces have too much data, which ruins pretty much every categorical construction (e.g., finite products).  But one can define an intermediate category (σ-algebras with σ-ideals of null sets) that has very good categorical properties and easily fits existing classical theorems of measure theory such as the ones mentioned above.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: This is described in more detail in http://mathoverflow.net/a/20820 and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable+locale.

Comment: Another useful category related to this discussion is the one where objects are measurable spaces (in whatever meaning) and morphisms are Markov kernels, i.e. measurable mappings from the first object to probability measures on the second object. There is a natural definition of a measure preserving kernel, so there is also another useful category where the objects are probability spaces and morphisms are Markov kernels.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I think Wikipedia's choice to call this the change-of-variables-formula is somewhat misguided. It's a useful formula, I give you that, but "change of variables" usually refers to the theorem that actually *computes* the push-forward measure in terms of the Jacobian.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: Yes, I would also call it the (general) 'transformation formula'.

Comment: I seem to have introduced ‘Measble’ to the nLab, and I probably did it because I always thought that ‘Meas’ was for measure spaces instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider the notation Bor or Borel for the category of measurable (often called Borel) spaces.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this alternative terminology. "measurable space" seems to be more modern than "Borel space". Is this correct?

Comment: Actually $\mathsf{Bor}$ looks really good. But then it's still open how to denote the category of measure spaces. (Or the category of measure spaces equipped with a $\sigma$-ideal, as suggested by Dmitri Pavlov.)

Comment: It's measur*able* spaces that need to be equipped with a $\sigma$-ideal pace Pavlov (measure spaces already are).