# A Grothendieck style reference for probability theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, pr.probability

This is a very vague question.

I am looking for an "EGA" type of reference for probability theory. This means (among other things) that I'm looking for a text which develops the theory "abstractly".

Comment: This might be of help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical

Comment: Do you already know the books of Dellacherie and Meyer: Probabilités et potentiel?