# Is the Pierce spectrum useful elsewhere in Mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, boolean-algebras

In Borceaux and Janelidze's *Galois Theories*, a construction of the [Pierce spectrum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pierce+spectrum) is given. It is the poset of ideals in a Boolean ring. It's construction is reminiscent of the Zariski spectrum in commutative ring theory, however I've not seen it used elsewhere.

**Q. Is the Pierce spectrum important elsewhere in mathematics?**

Comment: It's used by some people in ring theory.  For a boolean ring it is the Zariski spectrum. For a began ring it plays the role of the central primitive idempotents in an Artinian ring in that it encodes direct product decompositions by representing the end in a sheaf but not a sheaf of local rings.  If your ring is von Neumann regular it can be used to represent your ring as a sheaf of directly indecomposable rings.  You should see Pierce's memoir https://www.ams.org/books/memo/0070.

Comment: I believe Magid uses it in his galois theory for commutative rings.  We use it in https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.06952 to represent skew inverse semigroup rings as convolution algebras on groupoids

Comment: It *is* the Zariski spectrum (of a Boolean ring)!

Comment: Actually if the ring is von Neumann regular you get a sheaf of fields.  For a general ring you get it represented as the global sections of a sheaf of directly indecomposable rings over a compact totally disconnected space

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg "began ring" ?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I have a feeling auto-correct interfered more than once in your first comment. I couldn't parse "representing the end in a sheaf..."

Comment: @ToddTrimble, this is nearly as bad as when I was writing about the cosmological dimension of groups.  I meant representing the ring as the global sections of a sheaf of indecomposable rings.  When you have finitely many central idempotents you can do this via a direct product but otherwise you need to use sheaves and the Pierce spectrum is how to do it

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I should have spotted that. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 6):

For Boolean rings, the Pierce spectrum coincides with the Zariski spectrum
and is one of the functors implementing the
[Stone duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Stone%20duality) between Boolean algebras and compact
totally disconnected Hausdorff spaces and [Stonean duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+Boolean+algebra)
between complete Boolean algebras and compact extremally disconnected
Hausdorff spaces.

Restricting further to complete Boolean algebras of projections
of commutative von Neumann algebras produces
an equivalence of categories of commutative von Neumann algebras
and [compact strictly localizable enhanced measurable spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical/20820#20820),
i.e., a version of the Gelfand duality in the setting of measure theory.