# Is the opposite category of commutative von Neumann algebras a topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, von-neumann-algebras, topos-theory

By the "category of commutative von Neumann algebras" I mean the category of all commutative von Neumann algebras with normal unital $*$-homomorphisms between them (I don't want to restrict to separable predual as I think it would prevent the existence of finite products).

Of course, I don't really believe it is a topos. I would honestly be very surprised if it were but so far I can't find a clear-cut argument that would show that it is not a topos. Part of the problem is that products in this category are a bit tricky to understand.

On the other hand, it is not so far-fetched to suggest this, since this category has some topos-like properties: it's definitely a "category of spaces", it has a subobject classifier given by $\mathbb{C}^2$, subobjects of each object form a complete boolean algebra, it is extensive, and it might very well be a regular category (not so clear).

I don't think it is exact or cartesian closed (if it were any of these, that would make it a topos), but that's not something completely inconceivable either.

Does anyone have a clean argument to show that this category is *not* a topos ?

Comment: Counter-question (based on my own ignorance):   Every abelian von Neumman algebra on a separable Hilbert space is isomorphic to $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ for some $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$.    Measurable spaces are not Cartesian closed (by a result of Aumann).   Have I missed some subtlety?

Comment: @user1504 : I'm not familiar with the result you mention, it highly depends on what category it applies too exactly. Do you have a reference ? The restriction to separable Hilbert space might also be a big problem, as far as I understand, the coproduct of abelian Von Neuman algebra already don't preserve this conditions.

Comment: This one:  https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-5/issue-4/Borel-structures-for-function-spaces/10.1215/ijm/1255631584.full
I learned of it in this paper:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02547

Comment: Thans ! Ok, so (if I understand correctly what the paper is about),  it seems the paper is talking about exponential in the category of measurable space in the sense "set endowed with a $\sigma$-algebra". But morphisms between commutative Von Neuman algebra do not corresponds to maps but rather to equivalences class of maps up to equality almost everywhere, so while this is related, it does not directly answer the question. (But there might be interesting ideas there nonetheless). The main problem though is that product in this category is very different from coproduct of abelian VN algebras.

Comment: Is the category of commutative von Neumann algebras [balanced](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/balanced+category) (i.e. does epi + mono imply iso)?

Comment: @TimCampion: Monics and epics in commutative von Neumann algebras are precisely injective and surjective homomorphisms, which answers your question in the affirmative.

Comment: @user1504: Properties like cartesian closedness only transfer along equivalences of categories.  The correct formulation of this equivalence has only been written down recently in https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05284, see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical/20820#20820.  In particular, the fact that the category is not cartesian closed does not follow from Aumann's result.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov  Thank you.  Interesting paper!

Comment: I wonder if the exact completion is a topos...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The opposite category of commutative von Neumann algebras is not a topos
because categorical products with a fixed object do not always preserve small colimits.

See Theorem 6.4 in Andre Kornell's [Quantum Collections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2994v2).