# Two questions about subsequential spaces with countable $k$-network

Tags: gn.general-topology

This question was motivated by my answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57805/what-spaces-can-be-obtained-from-mathbbrn-by-taking-quotient-spaces-and), which asked about the characterization of spaces that belong to the smallest class of topological spaces that is closed under taking subspaces, quotient spaces and contains all Euclidean spaces $\mathbb R^n$. It turns out that this class coincides with the class of subspaces of sequential spaces of cardinality $\le\mathfrak c$ possessing a countable $k$-network.

So, the original problem has reduced to the problem of recognizing subspaces of sequential spaces with countable $k$-network.

Let [us recall](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419090117K) that a topological space is called *subsequential* if it is homeomorphic to a subspace of a sequential topological space.

A family $\mathcal N$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is called a *$k$-network* if for each open set $U\subset X$ and  compact subset $K\subset U$ there exists a finite subfamily $\mathcal F\subset\mathcal N$ such that $K\subset\cup\mathcal F\subset U$.

In the theory of generalized metric spaces, regular spaces with countable $k$-network are called *$\aleph_0$-spaces*.

> **Question 1.** *Let $X$ be a subsequential space with a countable $k$-network. Is $X$ a subspace of a sequential space with a countable $k$-network?*

I suggest that the answer to this question is negative and a suitable counterexample is constructed in Theorem 7.3 of [this paper of Franklin and Rajagopalan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419090117K), but I cannot prove that the countable subsequential space $PS$ of subsequential order $\omega_1$ constructed in this theorem can (or cannot) be embedded into a sequential spaces with countable $k$-network.

Another possible counterexample  to Question 1 can be the countable power $S^\omega_\omega$ of the Frechet-Urysohn fan $S_\omega$. We recall that $S_\omega$ is the quotient space of $S_1\times\mathbb N/\{0\}\times\mathbb N$, where $S_1=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the convergent sequence.

> **Question 2.** Is the space $S^\omega_\omega$ subsequential? If yes, does it embed into a sequential space with a countable $k$-network?