# Representing logic formulae in manifolds

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry

Is there a meaningful way to transform logical equations (for instance $a \implies b$; $b \land a \implies c$ etc.) into geometrical representation in spaces such $\mathbb R^n$, $\mathbb C^n$ or manifolds?

I am curious if there is a way to analyze logic equations via transforming them into geometrical objects. Sorry for being too ambiguous, I have no clue where to start looking at. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like this? https://mathoverflow.net/a/19156/21349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible interpretation of your somewhat vague question is discussed in Steve Vickers' book 'Topology via Logic'. The interpretation is more on the level of open sets than `big things' like manifolds, but the discussion in the early parts of the book may be useful for you to help you reformulate your question at a slightly more precise level.

Another point worth making is that there are MANY different logics. Have a look at Wikipedia on modal logics and in particular on S4 and S5. Again these operate on the level of the open sets, but some topological constructs lead to interesting logical consequences. The key idea is that of topological semantics of various logics.

A final area nearer to your manifolds etc. would be in interpretations of quantum logic in terms of cobordisms and other similar things. Here key ideas are more likely to be found in theoretical computer science papers or coming from theoretical physics. The ideas in both operad theory and quantum field theories are also worth glancing at but beware there are perhaps too very many directions in which that can lead you!

Comment: Thanks , I had a quick look at what you suggested. They all looked interesting and worth studying more in depth. Just to state my thoughts explicitly I was wondering if there is a way to map computational problems( SAT-solving problems etc) into "continuous" or "geometrical" object(I am being ambiguous again by using this word sorry lol~) and solve it using tools from geometry / mathematical analysis. Thanks I'll take a deeper look at all your suggestions.

Comment: @Tim_Porter and ahhaoment your questions and guidance today is more important than 4 years ago - today there are neural manifolds - one can be interested how the logics, theories can be represented in the space of possible activities of neuron network. I.e. there are N neurons, each neuron i can have activity level in [-1, +1] and N-dimensional cube (or rescaled space) is space of points in which each spoint can encode some theory in some logic. ... So - the value of this quesion has immense practical applications!

Comment: @ahhamoment you can have a look on the comment above. It would be nice if you can share some insight you have hot since this question was published.