# Tensor product of vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, tensor-products, geometric-intuition

The Whitney sum (where fibre dimensions add) of two real, or two complex, vector bundles $\pi : E \to X$ and $\pi' : E' \to X$   over a topological space $X$ is not hard to get an intuitive grasp of. Especially if you consider the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold embedded in Euclidean space and its normal bundle. (I'm mainly interested in the cases where $X$ is a smooth manifold.)

But I have never felt I had much intuition for what is going on *geometrically* when one takes the *tensor* product (where fibre dimensions multiply) of the bundles $\pi$ and $\pi'$, even though the definition is entirely familiar.

Perhaps the most interesting case is the Picard group of equivalence classes of complex line bundles over a complex manifold, under the operation of tensor product.

Can someone offer some geometrical intuition about what is going on when we take the tensor product of real or complex vector bundles?

Comment: Sum is the product or coproduct, i.e. it deals with issues of pairs of linear mappings.  Tensor products deal with bilinear functions.  So for example, $V^* \otimes V$ is naturally isomorphic to $Hom(V,V)$.  So these are the kinds of vector bundles that pop up when working with second derivatives, Hessians, etc.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that tensor product on the level of linear algebra is familiar to me. Just not the geometry of tensor products of vector bundles, which of course becomes the multiplication in K-theory.

Comment: For me the intuition is just that tensor product is analogous to multiplication of functions. Note that when tensoring line bundles on a scheme, the associated divisors add, the same as they do for functions. Consider the group of fractional ideals in a Dedekind domain: the ideals are not strictly speaking numbers, but passing to some extension of the fraction field any such fixed ideal becomes principal. The fractional ideals are directly analogous to line bundles on Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Here’s a question I am not qualified to answer. Topological vector bundles are all pullbacks of the tautological bundle on the classifying space. Can we give a geometric intepretation of the tensor product using this?

Comment: Perhaps the following is a bit too far-fetched, and I may be misinterpreting your question, but since you mentioned K-theory *as a ring* (with $\otimes$ being the product), the Chern character gives a homomorphism into rational cohomology of the base space. In fact, by work of Atiyah and Hirzebruch, the rational K-theory is isomorphic to the rational cohomology of the base space, if it is *a finite CW-complex*. So one can think of $E \otimes F$ in terms of a product in the rational cohomology ring, but idk off top of my head how much geometrically intuitive this line of thought can be made.

Comment: Do you have a geometric intuition for the tensor product of two finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: A class of vector bundles I like to consider for intuition are flat bundles, of the form V \times_G E over E/G = B say for discrete groups G.  Here as one goes around a loop in B whose endpoints differ by the action of some g when lifted to E, the bundle will be "twisted" by the action of g on V.  When V is one-dimensional, this will be a number.  For the tensor product of such line bundles these numbers are  multiplied.  My intuition more generally is "product of twisting" but of course that should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps the fundamental issue here is an unintended consequence of the orthodox set-theoretic foundations of mathematics, which can give the mistaken impression that mathematical objects need be encoded as sets in order to do math "properly", even if this comes at the cost of being able to intuitively understand these objects.

Let me explain (and be patient, I will get to tensor products of vector bundles eventually).  We are all familiar for instance with the concept of a function $f: X \to Y$, but strictly speaking a function is not a set and so does not directly exist inside a standard set theory such as ZFC.  But we have a standard solution to this: we *encode* a function $f$ within set theory by identifying a function with its graph $\Gamma_f := \{ (x,f(x)): x \in X \}$ (or, if one wants to be more pedantic, with the ordered triple $(X, Y, \Gamma_f)$ in order to record the domain $X$ and codomain $Y$, with the ordered triple itself being encoded as a set in some standard fashion).  Every function uniquely determines a graph and every graph uniquely determines a function (if we also specify the domain and codomain), so at a foundational level this is a satisfactory resolution to the problem of introducing functions into set theory. But it comes at the cost of intuition.  Consider for instance the problem of trying to define the pointwise product $fg: X \to {\bf R}$ of two real-valued functions $f,g: X \to {\bf R}$.  If we view a real-valued function $f: X \to {\bf R}$ as a real number $f(x)$ that is parameterized by some parameter $x \in X$, then the pointwise product is simply the ordinary multiplication operation on the real numbers, with the only difference being that the real numbers involved are not constant, but instead depend on a parameter $x$:
$$ fg(x) := f(x) g(x).$$
This is extremely intuitive (especially if $x$ is interpreted as a time variable, a position variable, or a state in a state space or probability space).  For instance, it is immediately obvious that all the usual commutative ring axioms for real numbers extend immediately to real-valued functions. However, if one insists on interpreting functions $f$ as graphs $\Gamma_f$, the definition suddenly becomes horrible:
$$ \Gamma_{fg} := \{ (x,c): \exists a,b \in {\bf R}: (x,a) \in \Gamma_f, (x,b) \in \Gamma_g, ab=c \}.$$
If one insists on the graph-based encoding as the "geometric" way to think about functions, then the operation of multiplying two functions together is now much more opaque than it needs to be.  For example, it is not obvious at all that this operation is associative.

The situation with tensor products (or many other standard operations) of vector bundles is completely analogous.  In our orthodox set-theoretic foundations, we define a vector bundle over a base $X$ as a set $E$ equipped with various structures (a projection map $\pi: E \to X$, a smooth structure on $E$, etc.) obeying various axioms.  But one can instead think of a vector bundle as a vector space $E_x$ which is not constant, but instead depends (continuously, smoothly, or holomorphically) on a parameter $x \in X$.  This is completely akin to viewing a function not as a graph $\Gamma_f$, but as a quantity $f(x)$ depending on a parameter $x$.  In many ways, the latter interpretation is more intuitive; but it is more difficult to shoehorn into the orthodox set-theoretic foundations of mathematics, so we use the former definition instead.  (See also [this previous MO answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/30231/766) for a related discussion.)  So one should often think of a vector bundle as a vector space that is varying in time, or in space, or is dependent on the state of a system, or whatever other interpretation is germane for the application at hand.  (Perhaps the fancy way of saying this is that vector bundles can be thought of as vector spaces in a [topos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos) over the base space.)

Anyway, once one adopts the parameterized point of view, the tensor product operation on bundles effortlessly generalizes the tensor product operation on vector spaces:
$$ (E \otimes F)_x := E_x \otimes F_x.$$
So whatever intuition you have for tensor products of vector spaces, now transfers instantly to vector bundles.

Comment: I think your point about the awkwardness of functions goes even deeper in the case of bundles. If $s \in \Gamma(U,E)$ is a section, then $\forall x \in U \colon s(x) \in E_x$, i.e. as a function $s$ takes each $x$ into a *different space* $E_x$, but to resolve this weirdness one then takes the (necessarily disjoint) union of the $E_x$-s, which puts everything back on solid set-theoretical ground. (This is of course perhaps a bit oversimplified, after all one *somehow* has to define a smoothly varying family of spaces rigorously within our set-theoretical foundations.) Cont.

Comment: Cont. I think this situation is even more pronounced in the world of schemes and their structure sheaves, e.g. for $X = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, if we think of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ as functions on $X$, then $n((p)) = \bar{n} \pmod p$, again sending each point into a different space... Going back and forth between the etale space POV and the functor POV for sheaves shows that one can realize abstract elements of rings as continuous functions (sections of the etale space), so maybe our definition of a function is not perfect.

Comment: Having said that, while I am not the downvoter and find your post interesting, I don't really think it addresses OP's question. My impression is that the OP understands the definition of vector bundles and their tensor product and is asking specifically for a **geometric interpretation** of $E\otimes F$ akin to how $E \oplus F$ is the ground for topological K-theory and akin to the Picard group in the case of line bundles.

Comment: I agree that the standard set-theoretic definition of a function isn't quite a perfect fit for all use cases, in particular the need to specify a single codomain to contain all outputs is slightly unnatural sometimes (even if the axiom schema of replacement guarantees that it can always be done).  As for your other point, the OP already appears to have some existing geometric intuition for tensor products of vector spaces; I hold that one just needs to relativize this intuition (replacing vector spaces/points with vector bundles/sections etc.) over $X$ to answer the question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. I am sure that OP understands the intuition of doing operations on a vector bundle pointwise. However, the actual construction is much more involved than that: one needs to provide local trivialisations which respect the differential geometry of the manifold of the base points. If one just provides the set of all fibres of a vector bundle, which basically is $M \times V$, one has not done any geometry at all! To turn $M \times V$ into the correct manifold, one has to get into the nitty gritty of sets, I fear.

Comment: As mentioned in Paul's answer, one can encode the geometry entirely through through the sheaf of sections, which is manipulated via the pointwise operations; local trivializations are not really required other than for setting up foundations.  For instance the sections of a tensor product $E_1 \otimes E_2$ of bundles are locally the linear combinations of formal products of sections of $E_1$ and $E_2$ separately, modulo bilinearity relations; this is just the pointwise application of the usual tensor product, but relativized so that points in a vector space become sections of a vector bundle.

Comment: If you want smooth geometry, you require the sections to be smooth.  If you want complex geometry, you require the sections to be holomorphic.  If you want discrete geometry, you allow arbitrary sections. And so forth.  One works in whatever topos is suited best for one's application.  But regardless of the choice of topos, the operations are pointwise, and are simply the relativizations of the absolute version of the operation to the topos at hand.

Comment: In orthodox set-theoretic foundations, functions are arbitrary by default, and additional regularity or geometry on the functions (continuity, measurability, smoothness, holomorphicity, algebraicity, etc.) has to be imposed by first adding additional structures (smooth structure, complex structure etc.) on the domain and codomain.  However one can alternatively replace the set-theoretic universe by an appropriate topos, in which case all the geometric structure comes "baked in" and all functions, objects, and spaces constructible within the topos automatically have the natural regularity.

Comment: Of course, the geometry of the topos may prohibit certain operations one is used to in set theory from being relativizable to that topos.  For instance, the law of the excluded middle or the axiom of choice may fail in the topos one is interested in.  But many concepts, such as tensor product, can be constructed in a way that avoids those prohibited operations (typically by working in some sort of "coordinate-free" formalism that avoids having to make artificial choices).  In which case the concept (and its intuition) transfers effortlessly from the absolute setting to the relative one.

Answer (score 9):

I guess we should start by speaking somewhat philosophically about what it means to think geometrically about bundles. For me, this usually means looking at their sections: either constructing interesting sections (e.g. the unit normal field to an oriented embedded hypersurface) or proving that sections with certain properties don't exist (e.g. nonvanishing vector fields on the 2-sphere). Note that this perspective doesn't actually lose anything: the functor which sends a vector bundle to its space of sections is an equivalence between the category of vector bundles over a compact Hausdorff space X and the category of finitely generated projective modules over $C(X)$.

So if we're willing to shift our focus from the bundle to the sections, it becomes clear that we think geometrically about tensor products all the time: for instance a Riemannian metric over a manifold $M$ is just a section of $(TM \otimes TM)^*$ with certain properties. Likewise the Riemannian curvature tensor is a section of

$$T^*M \otimes T^*M \otimes Hom(TM, TM)$$

It's admittedly a little hard to think straight about these bundles as bundles, but their spaces of sections contain subspaces which are easier to digest, like the space of Riemannian metrics or the space of curvature tensors. Basically any time you want to do linear algebra - bilinear forms, linear maps, eigenspace decompositions, etc. - parametrized by a base space, you have to work in a tensor bundle over that space.

Answer (score 4):

A rank-$n$ vector bundle over $X$ consists of a bunch of trivial vector bundles over open subsets $U_i$ covering $X$, patched together on the overlaps.  On each overlap $U_{ij}=U_i\cap U_j$, there is a map $U_{ij}\rightarrow GL_n(k)$ that describes the patching.   (This collection of maps is not, in general, unique.)

Given two rank-$n$ vector bundles $E\rightarrow X$ and $F\rightarrow X$, you can choose a single collection $\{U_i\}$ of open sets on which both bundles are trivialized.  The tensor product $E\otimes F$ is described by the tensor product of the patching maps.

In particular, a line bundle is a collection of trivial line bundles that get twisted and then patched together.  The tensor product of line bundles $E$ and $F$ is constructed by twisting once (as you would twist to get $E$), then twisting again (as you would twist to get $F$) and then patching.

More succinctly, a line bundle is an element of $H^1(X,GL_1(k))$ (where $H$ is Cech cohomology and $k$ is ${\mathbb R}$ for real vector bundles, ${\mathbb C}$ for complex vector bundles.  Tensor product of vector bundles corresponds to multiplication in Cech cohomology.