# The set of complements equal to the complement of set

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, lattice-theory

Consider $A \subset \{0,1\}^n$

I want $A$ to have two properties.

$1.$ $A$ is increasing, i.e., If $x \in A$ and $x \subseteq y$ then $y \in A$ too.

> [$x \subseteq y$ means that every coordinate of $y$ is greater that or equal to corresponding coordinate of $x$]

$2.$ $A^c$ is equal to set $B=\{x \mid x^c \in A\}$

Is there any characterization for such a set? I have to example for it. But I want to find an IFF condition for such sets...

$e1)$ $A=\{x|$ first coordinate of $x$ is  $1\}$

$e2)$ Fix an odd number of coordinates. $A= \{x\mid x$  contains at least half  of coordinates equal to $1\}$

`[For even number there is a similar example]`

---

P.S. Asked It before Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135708/when-set-of-complements-is-equal-to-complement-of-set

Comment: what does $\subset$ mean in $A\subset\{0,1\}^n$? why do we need $A^c$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I supposed it as power set lattice

Comment: Such sets are exactly the sets of the form $f^{-1}(1)$ for a self-dual monotone Boolean function $f$ of $n$ inputs.

Comment: Where you are taking complement? note that the first condition in 1 is better to be called upward closed rather than increasing.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek So, Is there any characterization of self-dual monotone boolean functions?

Comment: @Rahman.M This name arises from the origin of problem which is graph properties...

Comment: I don’t know what kind of characterization are you looking for. For one, they are exactly the functions definable by terms using variables and the three-variable majority function (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice). These functions have about as complicated structure as general monotone Boolean function, so you shouldn’t expect a simple explicit description of all such functions, or anything like that.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I thought that monotone functions are up closure of some generator set. Aren't they?

Comment: Yes, obviously. How is that supposed to help?

Comment: You said: "These functions have about as complicated structure as general monotone Boolean function"

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks to you, I've found it in Knuth's Art of computer programming.

Comment: Mentioning that it was previously posted on math.SE, with links, is the least you can do if you choose to post on both sites.

Answer (score 7):

Your two examples are of the following form:
Fix a collection $C$ of subsets of $n$ such that any two elements of $C$ have non-empty intersection and any other subset of $n$ either contains or is disjoint from an element of $C$. Then let $A$ be the collection of those subsets of $n$ which contain an element of $C$.

In the first example $C=\{\{0\}\}$ while in the second example $C$ is the collection of subsets of size $(n+1)/2$. It is not hard to show that any example must  be of this form.

Actually, a family $A$ satisfies conditions $1$ and $2$ if and only if $A$ is a **maximal intersecting family**. Here *intersecting* means that the intersection of any two members of the family is non-empty. To show this just note (for the "hard" direction) that if $A$ is a maximal intersecting family and $x$ is a subset of $n$ that does not contain any element of $A$ then $x^c$ intersects every element of $A$ and hence belongs to $A$.

Another characterization that follows easily from the one above but only works for finite $n$: A family $A$ satisfies $1$ and $2$ if and only if $A$ is intersecting and $|A|=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Can you say some other example? How can I show  that any example must be of this form?

Comment: Such families are usually called *maximal linked families* and there is an extensive literature in the context of the superextensions. The *superextension* $\lambda(X)$ is just the space of all maximal linked families over a set $X$. The superextension carries a natural Hausdorff topology turning it into a supercompact space. For a finite $X$ the superextension $\lambda(X)$ is finite (of course) and there exists some info on the cardinality of $\lambda(X)$. If $X$ is a semigroup, then $\lambda(X)$ has the natural semigroup structure, which was studied in (https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0796).

Comment: @TarasBanakh As already mentioned by the OP in a comment, one reference for that, with some more information, is in [Volume 4a](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc0b.pdf) of Knuth's "The art of computer programming", exercise 65. There is some related material in subsequent exercises, as well as details about self-dual monotone Boolean functions in the main text (around Theorem P).

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an ultrafilter without the intersection condition. So while  I don't know if it already has a name, you could call it an ultra-upset (as opposed to downset) or ultra-final segment.

Comment: So, Have you any idea that where can I look for it?

Comment: An ultrafilter without the intersection condition is known as a *majority* space, with majority voting being a natural example. There are various refinements to strict majority spaces, vast majority spaces, overwhelming majority spaces and so on. See links at https://mathoverflow.net/a/29815/1946

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins that's a good name, so I'm not "upset" anymore ;)

Answer (score 2):

Although [Emil Jeřábek](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12705/emil-je%C5%99%C3%A1bek) is certainly right in that these, as [Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4600/bj%C3%B8rn-kjos-hanssen) called them, ultraupsets, seem to be quite complicated, I would like to propose a combinatoric-topological reformulation which I think makes them more "touchable".

If we switch to complements, we are looking at [abstract simplicial complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) with a very special property - they contain exactly one from each pair of complementary simplices.

It seems that some of the consequences can be more easily understood with the aid of this geometric intuition. In particular one can visualize such complexes in low dimensions.

Among subcomplexes of an 1-simplex, only single points are possible.

For subcomplexes of a triangle, there are two possibilities: an edge of the triangle, and the discrete 3-element set of its vertices.

For a tetrahedron, one has three (up to isomorphism) possibilities: a 2-face, the disjoint union $($boundary of a triangle$)\cup($point$)$, and three edges meeting at a vertex.

For a 4-simplex one gets:

- a 3-face;
- disjoint union $($boundary of a tetrahedron$)\cup($point$)$;
- two kinds of complexes with 7 edges:

[image]

and

[image]

- a complex with 8 edges

[image]

- one with 9 edges

[image]

- and the whole 1-skeleton.

All in all this seems to be a very interesting combinatorial object.